# How to set the initial path of a Select File dialog in Adobe Air (Flex 3)

Tags: apache-flex, flex3, adobe, air

I'm using the Flex3 File.browseForOpen() method.  Is there a way to specify a initial path that the file browser starts in?

Comment: I ended up figuring this out about 2 minutes after posting, but for some reason my answer to myself isn't here.  The key part is that you need to hand the constructor a valid path, or else the FileBrowser will just navigate to the last File Explorer path you viewed.

Answer (score 3):

Create a File instance and pass in the directory you want to target in the constructor. Then if you call browseForOpen(), the directory will be the one you specified.